# validate column date format against another column value

Tags: excel, vba

if column Y is ER and column AB is not in date format mm/dd/yyyy or the reverse if column Y is not ER and column AB is in date format mm/dd/yyyy i want to show error message. code below is not working showing all as error

```
Sub check_Date()
   Dim c As Range, vY, vAB
   Dim lr As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In ws.Range("Y2:Y3" & lr)
        vY = c.Value
        vAB = c.Offset(0, 4).Value
        
        If (vY = "ER" And vAB <> mm / dd / yyyy) Or (vY <> "ER" And vAB = mm / dd / yyyy) Then
            MsgBox "Mismatch error at " & c.Address
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you mean to check the `NumberFormat`, or to check if it's a date using `IsDate`?

Comment: @BigBen not sure only dates in that format mm/dd/yyyy should be in column AB when column Y is ER, and only dates should be in column AB

Comment: Try using `IsDate` then.

Comment: What is in column A and what do you expect the range to be that you define here `ws.Range("Y2:Y3" & lr)`?

```
 lr = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  For Each c In ws.Range("Y2:Y3" & lr)
```

Comment: you are not using `option explicit` so the code `If (vY = "ER" And vAB <> mm / dd / yyyy)` is creating 3 variables all initialised as zero and so youll get an overflow. Is that what is happening?

Comment: The `vAB <> mm / dd / yyyy` part is comparing `vAB` to `mm` for equality (likely yielding `False`), then dividing it by `dd` (likely yielding `0`), then dividing it by `yyyy` (likely yielding a division by zero). You probably mean to compare `c.NumberFormat` with a string that looks like `"mm/dd/yyyy"`.

Comment: @JohnnieL iam not getting any errors or all errors  i am new what is the best way to write this code maybe what i have can be done different way

Comment: Also `Range("Y2:Y3" & lr)` is concatenating the last row (`lr`) with `Y3` so if your last row is 125 you're iterating cells in the range `Y2:Y3125`. Probably want to remove that stray `3` there ;-)

Comment: @kyohans05 is what you have posted here the actual code you have working? 

`If (vY = "ER" And vAB <> mm / dd / yyyy) Or (vY <> "ER" And vAB = mm / dd / yyyy)`

I cant see how this code can work unless mm, yyyy, dd are global variables defined elsewhere

Comment: i had done it this way before and it didn't work so i removed the quote marks  For Each c In ws.Range("Y2:Y" & lr)
        vY = c.value
        vAB = c.Offset(0, 3).value
        
        If (vY = "ER" And vAB.NumberFormat <> "mm/dd/yyyy") Or (vY <> "ER" And vAB.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy") Then